# Developer account SOAP API limits

Tags: soap-api

We have a developer account, but for some reason we can only use the SOAP API to query the 'test' dataset that was provided (and not any custom data we have entered). SFDC returns a blank dataset with no error. Is this type of query not allowed for developerforce accounts?

Comment: By Custom Data do you mean you have created a Custom Object, which has been populated with data rows ? There shouldn't be a limitation of this nature, unless the Profile of the User executing the API call hasnt been granted at least READ access to the Custom Object. Also Data Sharing, where the data needs to be accessible to the executing user.